# Typescript: Same generic type as resolved type of previous parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to know, how to specify that generic type if same as the one the resolved type of previous argument, when the type can be of multiple types.

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20add%3CT%20extends%20(number%20%7C%20string)%3E(a%3A%20T%2C%20b%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(typeof%20a%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20a%20%2B%20b%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20if%20(typeof%20a%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20a%20%2B%20b%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

```
function add<T extends (number | string)>(a: T, b: T): T {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        return a + b;
    } else if (typeof a === 'number') {
        return a + b;
    }
}

add('hello', ' world');
add(1, 1);
```

I want to be able to tell the compiler that all `T` are of same type, either number or string. I might missed some syntax. It might be possible with conditional types (to some extend)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't narrow the type of the generic parameter within the function. So when you test `a` this will not tell the compiler what the type of `b` is. And more importantly it will not tell the compiler what the return type of the function needs to be

```
function add<T extends (number | string)>(a: T, b: T): T {
    if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string') {
        let result = a + b; // result is string, we can apply + 
        return result as T; // still an error without the assertion, string is not T 
    } else if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
        let result = a + b; // result is number, we can apply +
        return result as T; // still an error without the assertion, number is not T  
    }
    throw "Unsupported parameter type combination"; // default case should not be reached
}
```

In this case though maybe having a dedicated implementation signature that works on the union instead (meaning no assertion is required) and public signature being the one you previously used.:

```
function add<T extends number | string>(a: T, b: T): T
function add(a: number | string, b: number | string): number | string {
    if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string') {
        return a + b;
    } else if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
        return a + b;
    }
    throw "Unsupported parameter type combination"; // default case should not be reached
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this warn you that the return value may be `undefined`?

Comment: @jcalz without strict null checks no ... I played with in the playground, will add a throw for the default return

Comment: This makes me sad... Do they intend to implement it someday?

Comment: Not sure, I don't follow the discussions that closely maybe @jcalz knows. Narrowing the generic type  seems to be a useful feature (I have seen a LOT of questions around here that asume this would happen)  but I am not sure what the implications of that would be

Comment: Do they intend to implement what?  If `T` is "hello", then `add("hello","hello")` would be required to return a value of type `"hello"`, which it won't.  So we don't really want the output to be `T`, but something like `T extends number ? number : string`, which is certainly implementable (although currently control flow analysis and conditional types don't play well together so you still need either assertions or one permissive overload implementation)